# PostgreSQL full-text search headlines do not contain enough context

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I'm using PostgreSQL's full-text search capability to implement a search feature on a client's site. I'm using the `ts_headline` function to get the context that the search terms appear in, but the client is not happy with the selection of words displayed. In particular, the headline seems to consistently begin with the search term, whereas the client would like it to start a few words earlier.

Is there any way to either configure PostgreSQL to have this behavior, or modify the ts_headline call to get the desired results?

**Edit**: Apologies for not including some sample SQL in the first place.

```
SELECT
    ts_headline('english', "text", plainto_tsquery('"endpoints"'))
FROM "Page"
WHERE to_tsvector("text") @@ plainto_tsquery('"endpoints"') 
ORDER BY ts_rank(to_tsvector("text"), plainto_tsquery('"endpoints"'))
```

Comment: I don't see an example of the statement you are using in your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the MaxFragments option, you might get better results.  Similarly you can play with MinWords and MaxWords, e.g.

```
SELECT
    ts_headline('english', "text", plainto_tsquery('"endpoints"'), 'MaxFragments=0, MinWords=5, MaxWords=9')
FROM "Page"
WHERE
    to_tsvector("text") @@ plainto_tsquery('"endpoints"') 
ORDER BY
    ts_rank(to_tsvector("text"), plainto_tsquery('"endpoints"'))
```

You will probably need to experiment.

See `MinWords`, `MaxWords` and `MaxFragments` in http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/textsearch-controls.html

Comment: That seems to be doing the trick (with some tweaking as you mentioned). Thank you very much!

Comment: If you want to display the entire thing, then use `HighlightAll=TRUE`